# Angular js routing not working properly, tried even CDN

Tags: angularjs

I can see changes in the url but the content in that page is not visible in ng-view please help. The following are the code files.

**Angular script**

```
<script>
var app = angular
                 .module("myapp", ["ngRoute"])
                 .config(function ($routeProvider) {
                          $routeProvider
                          .when("/Home", {
                              templateUrl: "Home.html",       
                          })
                          .when("/ThankYou", {
                              templateUrl: "ThankYou.html",                       
                          })
                      })                     
</script>
```

**Html code**
This is the main UI.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>       
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="angular-route.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head ng-app="myapp">
<body>
    <div>
        <a href="#/Home">Home</a>
        <a href="#/ThankYou">ThankYou</a>    
    </div>      
 <div ng-view></div>    
</body>
</html>
```

**Home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <div>
  Home
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var app = angular.module("Demo", ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/Home', {
      templateUrl: 'Home.html',
      controller: 'FirstController'
    })
  .when('/ThankYou', {
    templateUrl: 'ThankYou.html',
    controller: 'SecondController'
  })
});
app.controller('FirstController', function($scope) {

});
app.controller('SecondController', function($scope) {

});
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/MUaheTjIcqEVRMgvGF39?p=preview)**